# Integrating an exponential function with a product?

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations, reduction-of-order-ode

The original problem I was tasked with solving is

$$(x-1)y'' -xy' + y = 0$$

and given the solution $y_1(x) = e^x$.

I started working through the problem using this method (http://www.sosmath.com/diffeq/second/reduction/reduction.html) and got to $y_2(x) = e^x \int e^{-3x}(x-1)^{-1}dx$. How do I proceed from this point? How do I take this integral?

Sorry for the poor formatting, still new here.

Comment: I don't think there's an elementary antiderivative.

Comment: Let $u(x):=y(x+1)$.  Then, $u$ satisfies the differential equation $$x\,u''(x)-(x+1)\,u'(x)+u(x)=0\,.$$ Hence, $u(x)=a\,(x+1)+b\,\exp(x)$ for some constants $a$ and $b$, due to this link: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2866006/reduction-of-order-leads-to-non-elementary-integral.  Translate this back to $y$, we get $$y(x)=a\,x+\frac{b}{\text{e}}\,\exp(x)\,.$$

Answer (score 1):

**Remark:** by staring at the equation, we see that $y=x$ is another linearly independent solution. It's not always that easy, though...

---

I think you've gone wrong in your calculation. The point of reduction of order is basically to lose the lowest-order term, so that the last integration becomes easy. Putting $y=ue^x$, we find
$$ y' = (u'+u)e^x, \\
y'' = (u''+2u'+u)e^x, $$
and putting these into the equation,
$$ \left( (x-1)(u''+2u'+u) -x(u'+u) + u \right)e^x = 0, $$
so we can cancel off the $e^x$, and are left with
$$ (x-1)u'' +(x-2)u' = 0. $$
We now solve this as a first-order equation in $u'$. We have
$$ \int \frac{x-2}{x-1} \, dx = x - \log{(x-1)}, $$
so an integrating factor is $e^x/(x-1)$, so
$$ \left( \frac{e^x}{x-1} u' \right)' = 0. $$
Integrating and dividing,
$$ u' = A(x-1)e^{-x} \implies u = B + A\int (x-1)e^{-x} \, dx, $$
which is not what you have, but now this will give the right answer once you integrate by parts.