# Reduction of Order Leads to Non-Elementary Integral

Tags: calculus, integration, ordinary-differential-equations, reduction-of-order-ode

> If  $u_1=x+1$ is a solution of $$xu''-(x+1)u'+u=0$$ find another linearly independent solution using reduction of order.

I let $u_2=(x+1)v(x)$ be the second solution. Hence
$$v''(x^2+x)-v'(x^2+1)=0$$ Let $w=v'$, so 
\begin{align}
\frac{dw}{dx}(x^2+x)-w(x^2+1)&=0 \\
\frac{dw}{dx}&=\frac{(x^2+x)^{-1}(x^2+1)}{w^{-1}} \\
\text{ln}(w)&=\int \frac{x^2+1}{x^2+x} \ dx \\
\text{ln}(w)&=\int 1-\frac{1}{x}+\frac{2}{x+1} \ dx \\
\text{ln}(w)&=x+\text{ln}\left(\frac{(x+1)^2}{x}\right)+C \\
w&=C_1\frac{e^x(x+1)^2}{x} \\
v&=C_1\int \frac{e^x(x+1)^2}{x} \ dx
\end{align}
Where $$C_1\int \frac{e^x}{x} \ dx$$ cannot be solved. How do I find $v$?

Comment: There's nothing wrong with leaving the solution as an integral. Also, the last integral is the [exponential integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_integral)

Comment: The answer provided is $u_2=Ae^x$. I'd like to know, if possible, how they got this answer

Comment: If that's the case, then you must have done something wrong. I'd go back and check if your derived equation (second line) is correct

Comment: I will have another look, but I've read through it many times. I haven't found a mistake yet.

Comment: Your partial fraction expansion has an error.  The minus sign should be plus and the plus sign should be minus.  Maybe that will fix the final answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your work is correct up to the partial fractions

$$ \frac{v''}{v'} = \frac{x^2+1}{x^2+x} = 1 + \frac{1-x}{x(x+1)} = 1 + \frac{1}{x} - \frac{2}{x+1} $$

Integrating this gives

$$ \ln(v') = x + \ln x - 2\ln(x+1) $$
$$ \implies v' = \frac{xe^x}{(x+1)^2} = \frac{e^x}{x+1}-\frac{e^x}{(x+1)^2} $$

This has the form $e^xf(x) + e^xf'(x) = (e^xf(x))'$, therefore

$$ v(x) = \frac{e^x}{x+1} $$

I've ignored the integration constants, since they're already included in the general solution, which is

$$ u(x) = (x+1)(c_1 + c_2v(x)) = c_1(x+1) + c_2e^x $$

Answer (score 4):

$$xu''-(x+1)u'+u=0$$
$$x(u''-u')-(u'-u)=0$$
Let $v=u'-u$,
$$xv'-v=0$$
\begin{align}
xv' &= v \\
\frac{dv}{dx} &= \frac{v}{x} \\
\ln v &= \ln x + C \\
v &= Ax \\
u'-u &= Ax \\
u &= \dfrac{1}{\exp\left(-\int dx\right)}\int Ax\exp\left(-\int dx\right) dx \\
&= Ae^x\int xe^{-x} dx \\
&= Ae^x \left[-xe^{-x}-\int-e^{-x}dx\right] \\
&= Ae^x \left[-(x+1)e^{-x}+B\right] \\
&= k_1(x+1)+k_2e^x \\
\end{align}

Comment: Very nice! I hadn't thought of this.

Answer (score 0):

Define the operators $D$ and $X$ by $(D\,h)(x):=h'(x)$ and $(X\,h)(x):=x\,h(x)$.  For any function $\phi$, we also define the operator $\phi(X)$ to be $\big(\phi(X)\,h\big)(x):=\phi(x)\,h(x)$.   Observe that
$$D^2-\left(\frac{X+1}{X}\right)\,D+\frac{1}{X}=\left(D-1-\frac{1}{X}+\frac{1}{X+1}\right)\,\left(D-\frac{1}{X+1}\right)\,.$$

First, let $v:=\left(D-\dfrac{1}{X+1}\right)\,u$.  Then, $\left(D-1-\dfrac{1}X+\dfrac1{X+1}\right)\,v=0$.  Therefore,
$$v(x)=\exp\Biggl(\int\,\left(1+\frac{1}{x}-\frac{1}{x+1}\right)\,\text{d}x\Biggr)=a\,\left(\frac{x\,\exp(x)}{x+1}\right)$$
for some constant $a$.  Now, $v=\left(D-\dfrac{1}{X+1}\right)\,u$ implies that $D\,\left(\dfrac{1}{X+1}\,u\right)=\dfrac{1}{X+1}\,v$.  Hence,
$$u(x)=(x+1)\,\int\,\frac{x\,\exp(x)}{(x+1)^2}\,\text{d}x=(x+1)\,\Biggl(a\left(\frac{\exp(x)}{x+1}\right)+b\Biggr)=a\,\exp(x)+b(x+1)\,,$$
for some constant $b$.

---

Interestingly, you can also write
$$D^2-\left(\frac{X+1}{X}\right)\,D+\frac{1}{X}=\left(D-\frac{1}{X}\right)\,(D-1)\,.$$
That is,
$$D\,\Biggl(\frac{\exp(X)}{X}\,D\,\big(\exp(-X)\,y\big)\Biggr)=0\,.$$
Consequently, for some constant $A$,
$$\big(D\,\big(\exp(-X)\,y\big)\Big)(x)=-A\,x\,\exp(-x)\,,$$
making
$$y(x)=\exp(x)\,\int\,\big(-A\,x\,\exp(-x)\big)\,\text{d}x=A\,(x+1)+B\,\exp(x)\,,$$
for some constant $B$.